# Convert a string equation to an integer answer

Tags: python

If I have a string

```
equation = "1+2+3+4"
```

How do I change it into an int and equate the answer? I was thinking something like this but it would give an error.

```
answer = (int)equation
print(answer)
```

The equation could contain `+-*/`

Comment: You can try the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), but you may have to change your input string a bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are prepared to accept the risks, namely that you may be letting hostile users run whatever they like on your machine, you could use [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
>>> equation = "1+2+3+4"
>>> eval(equation)
10
```

If your code will only ever accept input that you control, then this is the quickest and simplest solution. If you need to allow general input from users other than you, then you'd need to look for a more restrictive expression evaluator.

**Update**

Thanks to @roippi for pulling me up and pointing out that the code above executes in the environment of the calling code. So the expression would be evaluated with local and global variables available. Suppress that like so:

```
eval(equation, {'__builtins__': None})
```

This doesn't make the use of `eval()` secure. It just gives it a clean, empty environment in which to operate. A hostile user could still hose your system.

Answer (score 5):

If we wanted to expose a calculator to the world, I'd be very interested to see if a cracker could work around this:

```
import string

def less_dangerous_eval(equation):
    if not set(equation).intersection(string.ascii_letters + '{}[]_;\n'):
        return eval(equation)
    else:
        print("illegal character")
        return None

less_dangerous_eval('1*2/3^4+(5-6)')
```

returns:

```
3
```

I know that this can be broken by giving it bad syntax (fixable with a try/except block) or an operation that would take up all of the memory in the system (try/except catching this might be more iffy), but I am not currently aware of any way for someone to gain control.

Comment: +1, although I'd prefer to check input against a whitelist of the small set of accepted characters, rather than a blacklist of others, though I don't think there's too much difference here. As to how it can be broken, the nearest I can get is `9**9**9**9**9**9` or some such thing raising a `MemoryError` probably.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you only have digits and plusses:

```
answer = sum(float(i) for i in equation.split('+'))
```

or if you know they will only be integers

```
answer = sum(int(i) for i in equation.split('+'))
```

If you want to be able to evaluate more than that, I suggest you do your homework:

- Look up the string module (which has string.digits)
- the math module, which has your operations
- create logic to perform the operations in proper order

Good luck!

Comment: For floats use `math.fsum` instead of `sum`.

Comment: Judging from the comments to the question, he actually wants to handle more general expressions

Comment: "create logic to perform the operations in proper order", very easy to say, not so easy to do!

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you use `eval` and check the input:

```
def evaluate(s):
    import string
    for i in s:
        if i not in "+-*/ " + string.digits:
            return False       # input is not valid
    return eval(s)
```

As already mentioned, `eval` is unsafe, and very difficult to make safe. I remember seeing a very good blog post explaining this, does anyone know what it was? However `ast.literal_eval` is safe, it doesn't allow `__import__` etc. I would strongly recomment using `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval` whenever possible. Unfortunately, in this case it isn't possible. However, in a different case, e.g. one where you only need to support addition and multiplication, you could (and should) use `literal_eval` instead.

On the other hand, if this is homework with the intention for you to learn about parsing, then I would suggest doing this a different way. I know that if I was a teacher, I would respond to an answer using `eval` with "Very clever, but this won't help you pass a test on abstract syntax trees." (which are incidentally one thing that you should look at if you want to implement this "properly").

Comment: -1: He specified that he needs to support multiplication and division.

Comment: I get malformed string error when I use that code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @sweeneyrod no, they are not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Python 3 currently seems to allow `+` and `-` in `ast.literal_eval`.  I was quite surprised to discover that, as I don't immediately see why it should.

Comment: @roippi Oh, I see! My example code is copied and pasted from a console session in Python 3.x. I didn't know the function behaved differently in prior versions.

Comment: The documentation, even for Python 3, doesn't make say that expressions can be evaluated in `literal_eval`.

Comment: @sweeneyrod no, multiplication and division are not supported under ANY python version.  Addition and subtraction are only in python 3.