# Python 3 - convert mathematical action to integer

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a string with a formula *5 - 3*, and I need to get the result in integer. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```
eval("5 - 3") # 2
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @ViliusPovilaika , Ok , but you should search SO first and then ask question , there is hunders of questions in SO , maybe similar one to your question founded!

Comment: Well I tried to look it up on SE and SO and came up with nothing. I guess I just don't know how to search right.

Comment: @ViliusPovilaika , try using similar key words for search , as you see duplicate question is very similar with your title , search more dude!

Comment: @Arman is right i just typed Convert a string equation to an integer answer  and find an  answer on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959333/convert-a-string-equation-to-an-integer-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
test = "5-3"
print(eval(test))
```

Gives 2

Comment: It works, thank you very much!